# jqueryui datepicker throwing error at code relating to zIndex

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui

I am developing an asp.net page/application.  I have created a textbox that i set as a datepicker using the datepicker from jqueryui.  in firefox and chrome the datepicker does not render.  in IE9 the date picker renders if i ignore the error.  the error is at line 644 in jquery.ui.datepicker.js.

the code where the error is thrown is here.

`inst.dpDiv.zIndex($(input).zIndex()+1);`

this is the message that VS displays when it catches the error

*Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method*

i'm not sure what is causing the issue.  I have looked for zindex issues, and the ones i'm finding are related to dialog appearing behind other elements.  i don't have the happening.

Comment: Please include some code if you want that other people can help. For example your head section, the textbox markup, the jquery initialization code, etc.

Comment: I've removed this code for now, but just to follow up.but my code pretty much was a copy/paste of examples on how to add the jqueary date picker.  http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ as an example of one resource i was using. only difference is i used asp textbox instead of an html textbox in my aspx file.  the text box attributes included id, runat, and a width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.zIndex() is not a jQuery method (search the jQuery API, nothing there)

You should use the .css('z-index','100')

Also a side note:

Whenever working in ASP .NET I do not use the $ sign to access jQuery I use

```
inst.dpDiv.zIndex(jQuery(input).zIndex()+1);
```

Depending on what ASP .NET framework you are using Win Forms, MVC etc the built in MSFT Ajax can collide with jQuery.

Comment: So the code that is breaking is the code that is directly from jqueryui.com.  should i be updating that js file?

Comment: ok now i have no idea what i must have done wrong.  i took the code out yesterday and moved on with my project.  today i put the code back in, and no errors o_O.

Answer (score 26):

Add `jquery.ui.core.js` will be OK

Answer (score 7):

I had this same issue and fixed it by making sure that I had the most current jQuery and jQuery UI referenced.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
$.zIndex = $.fn.zIndex = function (opt) {            
        var def = { inc: 10, group: "*" };
        $.extend(def, opt);
        var zmax = 0;
        $(def.group).each(function () {
            var cur = parseInt($(this).css('z-index'));
            zmax = cur > zmax ? cur : zmax;
        });
        if (!this.jquery)
            return zmax;

        return this.each(function () {
            zmax += def.inc;
            $(this).css("z-index", zmax);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I included(core files),

```
        ui.css and ui.core.js files
```

It's works for me..

Answer (score 0):

Axel22 gave the correct answer to solve this problem for me.

This is because the jquery-ui-datepicker.js script depends on the jquery-ui-core.js script.

This is made clear on the [jQuery Datepicker Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) page, within the 'Overview' tab, to the right, there is a list of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Add the script reference (../Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js) it will work
Refer to jquery.ui.core.js library

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution:

```
//inst.dpDiv.zIndex(jQuery(input).zIndex()+1); //we don't need it anymore

$.zIndex = '30000'; // i set the zindex at the higher value
```