# jQuery UI DatePicker give me an error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to use DatePicker from jQueryUI but get this error and didn't know what's the cause. Here is the error:

> TypeError: $(a).zIndex is not a function
>   http://cmv.loc/addons/shared_addons/themes/comvivem/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js
>   Line 5

I'm using other libraries as jQuery Tools and Foundation. You can test under http://comvivem.treswd.com/net/ login as demo/demo123 and go to Blog and there try to add a new entry under "Nueva entrada" at the form end you'll see a field called "Fecha" this is the one that trigger the DatePicker functionality and cause the issue. Any help?

Comment: might this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038349/jqueryui-datepicker-throwing-error-at-code-relating-to-zindex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to roll your own jQuery UI build instead of linking out to Google's CDN.  Try going [here](http://jqueryui.com/download) and selecting Core, Widget, and DatePicker (or everything if you need it).  Drop the new build in place (CSS, js) and see what happens.

Comment: Hi @joe this is exaclty what I did before try with Google CDN and get the same error

Comment: Where are you instantiating the DatePicker widget?  Example:  $('.datepicker').datepicker();

Comment: in file blog_form.js ... oh I see where it fails, for some reason the file is loaded before jQuery and before jQuery UI and at this level none object exists. Let me try change my code and see if after it works. Anyway thanks for your help/tip otherwise I never found the mistake :)

Comment: No, this isn't the error I loaded the file right after jquery.datepicker and still not working, uploading code to live server right away

Comment: Put the instantiation in $(document).ready(). It appears to be an order of operations issue.

Comment: Interesting.  Try creating a new text field with no validation and no formatting with a class of "datepicker" and then do $('.datepicker').datepicker(); only.

Comment: Yeah interesting just change to your suggestion and the same still even in a new field code updated at LIVE

Comment: There is definitely a conflict going on there.  Unfortunately, I'd have to be more familiar with the environment to say for sure.  You might just start commenting out script files one at a time until you can find the culprit.  Sorry, I couldn't be more help.  :)

Comment: Thanks for your time I found the issue. Foundation by default include jQuery 1.7.2 so the library was include twice! Cheers and thanks problem solve